# how to connect user input and lists

Tags: python, list

in my program, I am taking user input (integers 1-9) and having the user keep typing in numbers until they type 0 to exit. once they type 0 I want to print the sum of the integers and then exit. Im new to python so any help would be appreciated. Im getting an invalid syntax error when using the > and < symbol not sure why.

```
  def createList():
         myList=[]
         return myList



  def fillList(myList):
        for number in myList:
            if number >=1 and <= 9:
              number=int(input(" enter a number 1-9, and 0 to quit"))
              myList.append(number)
              return myList


  def printList(myList):
      for number in myList:
          print ( " the sum is" ,sum(myList))
          print(number)
          if number ==0:
              exit()

  def main():
      myList = createList()
      fillList(myList)
      printList(myList)


  main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only missing a word, try this:

```
if number >=1 and number <= 9:
```

So close!

Answer (score 0):

```
if number >=1 and number <= 9:
```

You need to place the variable on both sides of the and since they are two separate conditions.

Also, since you're initially creating an empty list, you will never get to the part where you get user input. To fix this you should use a while loop.

```
while number != 0:
```

The full program might look like this:

```
def createList():
     myList=[]
     return myList

def fillList(myList):
    number = 5
    while number != 0:
        if number >=1 and number <= 9:
          number=eval(input(" enter a number 1-9, and 0 to quit"))
          myList.append(number)

     return myList


def printList(myList):
  for number in myList:
      print ( " the sum is" ,sum(myList))
      print(number)
      if number ==0:
          exit()

def main():
  myList = createList()
  fillList(myList)
  printList(myList)


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_sum = 0
looping = True
while looping: 
    num = input("Enter a number (1-9) or 0 to exit.")
    if num.isdigit() and 0 <= int(num) <= 9:
        _sum += num
        if num is 0:
            looping = False
print("Sum is", _sum)
```